# Bear-charming technique has had ____ influence on tourism industry

Tags: single-word-requests

> Bear-charming technique has had ____ influence on tourism industry.

I think there is a common choice of adjective with a meaning similar to *expansive*, *widespread*, or *all-reaching* used in this context before the word *influence*, but I can't seem to recall exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *adjective* you are looking for is -

## Extensive

According to [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/extensive), the synonyms of extensive are -

> broad, deep, ***expansive***, extended, far-flung, ***far-reaching***,
> rangy, sweeping, wide, wide-ranging, ***widespread***

Therefore,

> Bear-charming technique has had ***extensive*** influence on the tourism industry.